# visual studio 2015 node modules central location

Tags: node.js, gulp, visual-studio-2015

I start using node modules a few months ago with visual studio (I have no prior experience with them) and I really like them. Using gulp etc is helping me a lot to deploy my asp.net apps but I have a problem with modules file and folders in each projects thousands of folders and files, is there any way to centralize those modules and keep using the visual studio and Package.json file as it is ?

Thanks

---Edit -----
Right now when I add a new module to package.json, installed node modules stored under node_modules under project Folder
it is working like Visual studio 2013 nuget packages (nuget packages stored under individual projects)
what I need is finding a way to install those modules globally and use them with package.json  and not having thousands folders under node_modules in every freaking project I use node

I am looking for a solution what they did for nuget packages in visual studio 2015, they keep all package files under [UserAccountFolder].dnx\packages
instead of individual projects

Comment: what you mean by `centralize those modules`, can you please provide more context

Comment: I mean, right now whenever I added modules (like gulp grunt or gulp-uglify ) into package.json file in project folder ** node_modules ** folder contains all node modules, each project keep it's own node modules

Comment: ok so what is the problem? your question is not clear... can you edit the question, write it with example of what you want or expect

Comment: I am looking for a solution as well. I ran into a really bad problem with Visual Studio 2015 not even wanting to open up the project given the depth of dependencies of node modules (read: tons of nested folders). Here is an article highlighting the issue and a potential solution for that problem. However, it would be nice to specify a central location (like solution root like Nuget does).
http://blog.icanmakethiswork.io/2015/06/npm-please-stop-hurting-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

Half of the solution may be under Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools. You should see the path for node modules as ".\node_modules.bin" . I switched mine to "..\node_modules.bin" but did not see a change in where the modules were downloaded.